# Update a lookup field to 'Null' (remove existing value) in FLOWS

Tags: visual-workflow, flow-screen-component, flowscreen

I have got a lookup field on an object, which I would like to update to Null/blank (remove the existing value) using FLOWS.

I have tried to use {!$GlobalConstant.EmptyString} but its not working, there is no null global constant in this format. However I was able to save $GlobalConstant.Null (without the braces) but still no result.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try just leaving it blank with out any value?

Comment: This should work both with empty value and `{!$GlobalConstant.EmptyString}`. Did you check if you have added any condition while updating the record and also any custom logic that is populating it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is leave the field value blank. I have tried as below:-

[image]

Just left the field blank

[image]

When i debugged it,

[image]

and i tried on record edit by activating the flow as well, it worked.

else, you can create a formula as well

[image]

Comment: the final solution with formula worked...as I was un-assigning the lookup in a loop, other solutions are not working. Anyway will further look into it. Thanks @Sanket